# Finding Credit Risk Population Data

Tags: data, risk, market-data, modeling, credit

Are there any free or relatively cheap sources of aggregate data on credit risk for specific geographic regions, ages, and so on?

Comment: What kind of data do you look for exactly, which region, attributes? You probably have tried World Bank, FRED, EuroStat etc. already, right?

Comment: @RndmSymbl I have, yes.  I am looking for Canadian consumer credit market data.

Answer (score 2):

If you need data for the EU, you can look here - http://www.eba.europa.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Free? I'm still looking myself.

Paid? Equifax, Moody's, S&P.